# How does one regulate audio from different programs in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

When I am chatting with someone in Skype, I want to mute any audio coming out of Chrome. Is this possible on a Windows machine?

Comment: What Operating System do you use? XP? 7? Vista?

Comment: look at the tags ;)

Comment: Aha! Thanks, heh, still getting acclimated to this site, I'm used to forums without tags where people have to put all the information in the posting. In that case i have a possible answer, I will post it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to Control Panel -> Sounds -> Communications tab. Put the radio button in "Mute All other sounds". See if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Leftclick on the sound icon (the speaker) in your taskbar once. At the bottom you will see the text "mixer" (of course other text in localized versions of win7). There you can define the sound level for each application that is currently active.

Comment: This will not solve his problem but rather give him manual control at the time he diecides to open the mixer. He wants the sound from everything but Skype to go away when he takes a skype call.

Comment: I don't see where that has been asked in the quesion. @Chi Zeng, please reword your question in that case.

Comment: True enough as well, I guess I assumed on that aspect. Chi is that what you were looking for? Or were you just looking to turn down or mute sound in general manually each time a call or chat session occurs?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Manual control works fine for me, though it's certainly nice for that to be automated. Thanks!